# Select Max Data from Subquery SQL, but it Show All Results from Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

```
SELECT MAX( t.valuesum ) AS total, t.codebook
FROM (
    SELECT SUM( value ) AS valuesum, codebook
    FROM stock
    GROUP BY codebook
) t
GROUP BY t.codebook
```

In the subquery, the output is :

```
b001 35,
b002 20,
b0003 11
```

I want to only see: b001 35. Please help me.

Comment: it my database      CREATE TABLE `stock` (
  `no` float NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `codebook` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `value` float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`no`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

-- 
-- dump ตาราง `stock`
-- 

INSERT INTO `stock` VALUES (1, 'b001', 20);
INSERT INTO `stock` VALUES (2, 'b002', 10);
INSERT INTO `stock` VALUES (3, 'b001', 15);
INSERT INTO `stock` VALUES (4, 'b003', 2);

Comment: i am sorry  . i am very bad skill english

Comment: Seems you have a column called "value" ? isn't it?

Comment: It's good to add a tag with the DBMS you are using (MySQL, SQL-Server, DB2, etc.) You would have got answers faster that way.

Comment: Not all 3 tags! The one you are supposed to use!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1st solution using `where` condition:

```
SELECT t1.valuesum, t1.codebook
FROM (
        SELECT SUM( s.value ) AS valuesum, s.codebook
        FROM stock s
        GROUP BY s.codebook
     ) t1
WHERE t1.valuesum in (SELECT MAX( t2.valuesum ) AS total
                     FROM (
                             SELECT SUM( s2.value ) AS valuesum, s2.codebook
                             FROM stock s2
                             GROUP BY s2.codebook
                           )t2
                     )
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e11ee/9/0) Demo

2nd solution using `having` condition:

```
SELECT max(t1.valuesum), t1.codebook
FROM (
        SELECT SUM( s.value ) AS valuesum, s.codebook
        FROM stock s
        GROUP BY s.codebook
     ) t1
GROUP BY t1.codebook
HAVING max(t1.valuesum) = (SELECT MAX( t2.valuesum ) AS total
                     FROM (
                             SELECT SUM( s2.value ) AS valuesum, s2.codebook
                             FROM stock s2
                             GROUP BY s2.codebook
                           )t2
                     )
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e11ee/18/0) Demo

Comment: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 't1.valuesum' in 'field list'

Comment: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: it ok ! Yes you help my life   if i want to use group in group what the way i can do

Comment: I'm not sure what do you need. I added 2nd solution, maybe it will help you.

Comment: I'm glad to help you again :) Don't forget to accept the answer to close the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT SUM( value ) AS valuesum, codebook 
FROM stock 
GROUP BY codebook
ORDER BY valuesum DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: it show   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 SUM( value ) AS valuesum , codebook  FROM stock  GROUP BY codebook  ORDER BY v' at line 1

Comment: I forgot that it is MySql and not MS SQL.
Edited my answer. Use Limit 1 to get top 1 row.

Answer (score 1):

You can simple get it by single query -

```
    SELECT MAX( t2.valuesum ) AS valuesum, t2.codebook
    FROM (
          SELECT SUM( s2.value ) AS valuesum, s2.codebook
          FROM stock s2
          GROUP BY s2.codebook
         )t2
```

DEMO : - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c2534/15

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM
(
  SELECT SUM([value]) AS valuesum, codebook
  FROM stock
  GROUP BY codebook
)
ORDER BY valuesum DESC
```

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to

Comment: it show   #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 SUM( value ) AS valuesum , codebook  FROM stock  GROUP BY codebook  ORDER BY v' at line 1

Comment: Edited. Pls check now. "value" is a keyword. we should use [value] instead for column name

Answer (score 0):

Assuming (from the comments and the error messages) that you use MySQL:

```
SELECT SUM( value ) AS valuesum, codebook
FROM stock
GROUP BY codebook
ORDER BY valuesum DESC
  LIMIT 1 ;
```