# How to select max value from a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create a query who take the maximum value from a jpa query

first i have:

```
select count(se.idSecteur) from Site si left join Secteur se on si.idSite = se.idSite group by si.idSite
```

This return :

```
19
22
22
16
26
27
15
24
29
17
13
32
...
```

I would like to create a query for have only the max value (32 here)

I tried something like :

```
Select max(select count(se.idSecteur) from Site si left join Secteur se on si.idSite = se.idSite group by si.idSite) ...
```

But it didn't work

Any advice is appreciated !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select Max Data from Subquery SQL, but it Show All Results from Subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12562389/select-max-data-from-subquery-sql-but-it-show-all-results-from-subquery)

Answer (score 2):

a simple way for mysql  is based or first rows  order by desc

```
  select count(se.idSecteur) 
  from Site si 
  left join Secteur se on si.idSite = se.idSite 
  group by si.idSite
  order by  count(se.idSecteur)  DESC 
  LIMIT 1
```

or you could use your result as subquery for max

```
  select max(my_value)
  from (
    select count(se.idSecteur) my_value 
    from Site si 
    left join Secteur se on si.idSite = se.idSite 
    group by si.idSite
  ) t
```